# Limit the output range of Skip32

Tags: postgresql, encryption

[Skip32](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Skip32) encrypts or decrypts a single int4 (32 bits) value with a 10 bytes (80 bits) key of bytea type.

Is it possible to limit the output to 100,000,000 - 999,999,999 so we always get 9 digits positive integers?

There is pseudo encrypt constrained to an arbitrary range [example](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pseudo_encrypt_constrained_to_an_arbitrary_range) in the wiki but it doesn't work with a key and only support setting the upper limit.

Do I need to modify the following lines in the original implementation?

```
  ...
  wl := (val & -65536) >> 16;
  wr := val & 65535;
  ...
  RETURN (wr << 16) | (wl & 65535);
  ...
```

and wrap in a loop that ensures the result is between the min,max range?

```
CREATE FUNCTION bounded_skip32(VALUE int4, CR_KEY bytea, ENCRYPT bool, MIN int, MAX int) returns int AS $$
BEGIN
  LOOP
    VALUE := skip32(VALUE, CR_KEY, ENCRYPT);
    EXIT WHEN VALUE <= MAX AND VALUE >= MIN;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN VALUE;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql strict immutable;
```

Comment: This general area of cryptography is called [format-preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) or sometimes range-preserving encryption. That wikipedia article mentions several algorithms.